# Tumble dryer heater element

Tags: power-supply, power

The heater element on my tumble dryer died, ordered a new one using my model number etc. The problem I have is that the original element is rated 240 V and 1050 W, the replacement sent is 240 V and 2100 W. So basically is it safe to use the new part on the tumble dryer?

Comment: Most likely not. Pretty sure there is a thermoswitch but it can only measure somewhere *near* the heater, so there is a time lap in which the heater grossly overheats its direct surroundings before the thermoswitch could stop it.

Comment: I assume you’ve double checked the original but 1050W sounds very low for a clothes dryer. 2-5kW is more typical for a full size dryer.

Answer (score 2):

A minor change in the power of the element will not make much of a difference in terms of performance or safety, but in your case the element that was sent to you is twice of the power of original element. Using this element is very risky, as the wiring and switches and all protection parts are sized for the lower current, and therefore are likely to fail, or worse overheat and cause fire.

Tumble driers are already enough in the news for causing fires, and you would not want a fire in your family home.

I suggest that you send the new element back, and have the correct one shipped to you.

Comment: just recieved call from technical department and they say its fine and that the thermal cut off thats installed on the element unit would stop it overheating. so basically it will heat up a lot quicker.

Comment: Get them to put it in writing in an email to you.
It is true that i will heat quicker, as well as the thermal cut-off will act at the same temperature, but it remains a fact that the wiring inside the dryer is not rated for that heating element, as well as the thermal cut-off might not work as it has to break a load that is twice of what it was designed for.

Comment: thanks Elmesito, the thermal switch comes installed on the new element so I would think it would be rated for the 2100w. will get them too put it in writing what their engineer has said.